# Conditionally set Disabled and Checked attributes on HTML Elements

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a button and a checkbox in a template field in an asp GridView.  I want the disabled property of the button and the checked property of the checkbox to be set conditionally based on the Data Field Expiration.  If Expiration equals Permanent, then the button should be disabled and the checkbox checked.  If not, then the button is enabled and checkbox unchecked.  I've tried:

```
<input type="button" id="expiration" disabled='<%# (string)Eval("Expiration") == "Permanant" ? "disabled" : "enabled" %>' value='<%# Eval("Expiration") %>'/>
<input type="checkbox" id="permanent" checked= '<%# (string)Eval("Expiration") == "Permanant" ? "checked" : "unchecked" %>'/>
```

But it seems that just having the disabled and checked attributes listed at all is causing all buttons to be disabled and all checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`disabled` and `checked` are boolean attributes. They accept **only** the values `disabled` and `checked` respectively.

If you don't want the control to be checked/disabled by default then *do not include the attribute at all*.

Since they are boolean attributes, you may omit everything except the value.

```
<input type="button" 
       id="expiration" 
       <%# (string)Eval("Expiration") == "Permanant" ? "disabled" : "" %> 
       value='<%# Eval("Expiration") %>'>
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="permanent" 
       <%# (string)Eval("Expiration") == "Permanant" ? "checked" : "" %>>
```

Your checkbox should have an explicit value though, see the comment in the DTD:

```
  value       CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- Specify for radio buttons and checkboxes --
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost works.  But now the issue is having the attribute disabled in quotations marks. It doesn't actually disable the button until the quotations marks are removed, but if I remove them from the Eval I get "The name 'disabled' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Nevermind.  That was my own stupidity.  It was single quotes and they were coming from before and after my Eval.  Removed those and all works. Thanks!